# Use array of strings for comparing in Where-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I have a user list of Active Directory that I retrieve this way:

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" )} -Properties Description
```

The problem is that I have a specific set of users that is based in their description:

- Admins
- Secretaries
- Mail men

What I do is create sublists like this:

```
$Admins = $users | Where-Object Description -eq 'Administrator'
```

The problem however is, that there is no standardization. The person who creates an user can write 'Admin' or 'Administrator' or 'adm',... which causes my sublist not to contain all users that are an admin.

What I did is that I created an array of strings:

```
$Admin_User_Strings = @("adm", "admin", "administrator")
```

And I wanted to use this array in my sublist but this appearantly doesn't work:

```
$Admins = $users | Where-Object $Admin_User_Strings -contains Description
```

I get the errror:

> Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

So my question is, how can I let the following line:

```
$Admins = $users | Where-Object Description -eq 'Administrator'
```

accept more ways of 'Administrator' inputs?

Comment: `Where-Object {$Admin_User_Strings -contains $_.Description}` or `Where-Object Description -in $Admin_User_Strings`

Comment: or `Where-Object Description -like adm*`

Comment: No one is stopping you from using `"` or `'` :-)

Comment: oh okay I wasn't aware of that detail. heel erg bedankt alleszinds

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have several options:

`$users | Where-Object {$Admin_User_Strings -contains $_.Description}`

or: `$users | Where-Object $_.Description -in $Admin_User_Strings`

or: `$users | Where-Object $_.Description -match "adm|admin|administrator"`

Comment: thanks, the `-match`-option will help me out a lot. Thanks Mosh

Comment: `-in` worked great for me, thanks!